# Login with google gives me an ApiException: 10

Tags: android, google-api, google-signin

I try to do a Google LogIn following this steps:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in

I have the google login button and I can put my email and password (and also I received an email to my google account telling me that someone (me) is using my account). But I received an ApiException: 10 exception and I cannot get the email from "account.getEmail();"

I post my code below, hope it helps:

MainActivity code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {



TextView txtEmailGoogle;

GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;

//Valor de login correcto de Google
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Login de Google
    txtEmailGoogle = findViewById(R.id.txtEmailGoogle);
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestIdToken("1111111111111-000a0aaaa0a00aaaaa0aaa0000a00aa.apps.googleusercontent.com")
            .build();

    // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.sign_in_button:
            signIn();
            break;
    }
}

private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
        // a listener.
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(task);
    }

}

private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
    try {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);

        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        txtEmailGoogle.setText("Email: " + account.getEmail());
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
        // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Google login attempt failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}    
}
```

I use the client ID given by "Configure a Google API Console project" section of the first link I posted at the begining of the question.

The error is:

```
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 19989 on device Android_Accelerated_x86_Nougat [emulator-5554]
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xad005cc0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xad0039a0)
W/System.err: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: 
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzb.zzy(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at com.example.iknovatio.appslogin.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:211)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6932)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4085)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4132)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1533)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xad005cc0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xad0039a0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xad005cc0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xad0039a0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xad005cc0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xad0039a0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xad005cc0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xad0039a0)
```

Can anyone helps me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Same problem I am also facing. did you solve this issue?

Comment: Hi, I have to face the same problem any anyone found a solution?